# DirectShow and GDI buffer

Tags: directx, directshow, gdi, screen-capture

I want to capture screen, but I have a window that is showing  Video from capture card with directshow. In Some PCs the captured part in recorded screen is empty(dark) because of unknown reason. When I capture screen with DirectX the problem goes away. but I use  a third party library (Microsoft expression encoder screen capture) the problem still remains. Is DirectShow buffer differ from desktop GDI buffer?How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I think its related to video overlay